# How to Delete images from phone gallery using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

Hello i am developing app lock on flutter which move your gallery photo to application directory folder with help of file_picker  plugin.And i have successfully copied gallery photo to my application directory but issue that i wanna delete orginal image from phone photo gallery.Image is not deleting as filepicker.path is returning cache image path not the original path of selected image.here is my code below

```
  Future<void> pickImage() async {
    try {
      final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowMultiple: true,
        type: FileType.image,

      );

      if (result != null && result.files.isNotEmpty) {
        final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final imagesDir = Directory('${appDir.path}/images');

        if (!await imagesDir.exists()) {
          await imagesDir.create(recursive: true);
          print('Created directory: $imagesDir');
        }

        for (var file in result.files) {
          final fileName = file.name;
          final filePath = file.path;
          final newPath = '${imagesDir.path}/$fileName';


          // Move the image file to the images directory
          final File sourceFile = File(filePath!);
          final File destinationFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);

          print('Moved image: ${destinationFile.path}');

          await sourceFile.delete();
          print('Deleted image: $filePath');
        }

        refreshScreen();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error picking images: $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### WORKING SOLUTION ✨

###### If you're using `file_picker`, I'm sure you have access to `path` attribute from returned `XFile` object.

This simple deletes the file, based on path passed to the function

```dart
Future<void> deleteFileBasedOnPath(String imagePath) async {
  final FileManager fileManager = FileManager();
  final bool isDeleted = await fileManager.deleteFile(imagePath);

  if (isDeleted) {
    // Image successfully deleted, Handle event

  } else {
    // Failed to delete image, Handle event
  }
}
```

Then update your method like so:

- Instead of calling `await sourceFile.delete();`
- Call `deleteFileBasedOnPath(filePath);`

That's it, that's all ✅

#### Happy coding ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: is not returning actually image path its return cache path

Comment: Yes! But knowing that you already have filePath, you can pass it to the function, for the file to be deleted.

Comment: Or, you can get all file paths, then pas it to the function as a List<String>

Comment: This will delete images from phone gallery?